# Thickbox Overlay affecting all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, thickbox

I am currently doing some work on a site.

My problem is that, when clicking Thickbox slideshow images, the page overlay executed onclick appears to affecting the whole website canvas including the thickbox element itself (The thickbox element is suppose to stand out)

There should only be an overlay on the background elements and the thinkbox should not be behind the overlay css entry - Essentially all we're getting is the below:

Thanks very much for your help, would be nice to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

On line 399 of `nggallery.css`:

`#TB_window { z-index: 9999 !important; }`

Remove that line.

Thickbox itself has everything it needs to work correctly inside of `thickbox.css`. Modifying those CSS rules with selectors in other stylesheets should be kept to a minimum, unless you know what you're doing.

This is easily debugged by right clicking on the window, clicking "inspect element" and then looking at the CSS rules applied to `#TB_window`